# Ubuntu web browser does not start after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: permissions, 16.04, webbrowser-app

I have recently updated my Ubuntu installation from 15.10 to 16.04. After it the Ubuntu web browser app does not start. Here is the console log:

```
(webbrowser-app:7778): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user': Brak dostępu.  dconf will not work properly.

(webbrowser-app:7778): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user': Brak dostępu.  dconf will not work properly.

(webbrowser-app:7778): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user': Brak dostępu.  dconf will not work properly.
Failed to launch single instance: "QLocalServer::listen: Permission denied"
```

Is it a bug? Can I fix/work around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out finally. The directory ~/.local/share/webbrowser-app has been owned by root, not by me. Solution was then as simple as using chmod.